# How to solve equations like these?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, transcendental-equations

If $f(x) = x^{2} - \frac{\cos x}{2}$ and $g(x) = x\frac{\sin x}{2}$.
Find the points at which $f(x) = g(x)$.

I'm stumped and have no idea how to proceed or solve questions like these.

Comment: I don't think $$2x^2 = x\sin x + \cos x$$ has an analytic solution. Are you asking about numerical methods?

Comment: @gt6989b I'm trying to solve it analytically. Is it not possible?

Comment: It is not possible. Here are numerical solutions: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2+%3D+x*sin+x+%2B+cos+x

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, it is impossible, or difficult, to find an analytic solution. You can use NR to approximate $f(x)=0$ for $f(x)=2x^2-x\sin x-\cos x$:
$$\begin{align}
x_{n+1}&=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}\\
&=x_n-\frac{2x_n^2-x_n\sin x_n-\cos x_n}{4x_n-\cos x_n}\\
&=\frac{(x_n^2-1)\cos x_n-x_n(\sin x_n+2x)}{x_n(\cos x_n-4)}
\end{align}$$
$$$$
Thus with sufficient iterations, you get $x=0.7101850989$, which gives $f(x)=0$.